# Write to Plist in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I am trying to write to a plist in xcode. What I've written works, except the plist file doesn't change. I've tried a few different implementations of this, and reaching the same result.

Here is the code:

```
func saveGameData() {

    let BedroomFloorKey = "BedroomFloor"
    let BedroomWallKey = "BedroomWall"
        var bedroomFloorID: AnyObject = 101 as AnyObject
        var bedroomWallID: AnyObject = 101 as AnyObject
    
      let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as NSArray
      let documentsDirectory = paths.object(at: 0) as! NSString
      let path = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("room.plist")
        
        print("PATH", path)

      let dict: NSMutableDictionary = ["XInitializerItem": "DoNotEverChangeMe"]
      //saving values
      dict.setObject(bedroomFloorID, forKey: BedroomFloorKey as NSCopying)
      dict.setObject(bedroomWallID, forKey: BedroomWallKey as NSCopying)
      //...

      //writing to GameData.plist
      dict.write(toFile: path, atomically: false)

      let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
      print("Saved GameData.plist file is --> \(resultDictionary?.description ?? "")")
    }
```

My plist is in the main directory of my xcode project, same folder as were the ViewController is.

Thanks

Comment: "What I've written works, except the plist file doesn't change. " Then how exactly does it "work"? Does the line `print("PATH", path)` print what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write into the application bundle, for obvious reasons the bundle is read-only.

Your code writes the plist into the `Documents` directory in the container of the application. If you have a default Property List file in the application bundle copy it on the first launch of the app into the Documents directory.

However the code looks like a ugly literal translation of Objective-C code. This is a native Swift version

```
func saveGameData() throws {
    
    let bedroomFloorKey = "BedroomFloor"
    let bedroomWallKey = "BedroomWall"
    let bedroomFloorID = 101
    let bedroomWallID = 101
    
    let documentsDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let url = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("room.plist")
    
    print("PATH", url)
    
    var dict : [String:Any] = ["XInitializerItem": "DoNotEverChangeMe"]
    //saving values
    dict[bedroomFloorKey] = bedroomFloorID
    dict[bedroomWallKey] = bedroomWallID
    //...
    
    //writing to GameData.plist
    let data = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: dict, format: .xml, options: 0)
    try data.write(to: url)
    
    print("Saved GameData.plist file is --> \(dict)")
}
```

There is no need to reread the data. If no error is thrown the plist has been written successfully.

Comment: thank you for the explanation and code rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

You create a plist file inside documents

```
let path = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("room.plist")
```

which isn't same as the file located in your main bundle ( same level as `ViewController.swift` ) which won't accept any write as bundle is signed with the app and can't accept any change

Comment: Ok I see, where is documents relative to my project though?

Comment: documents folder is created by ios for your app you have no browse access to it with your project hierarchy file